# Can I see in history output from which directory I had actually issued a command?

Tags: command-line, command-history, tcsh, csh

<kbd>CTRL+R</kbd> allows me to reverse search through the command history which is great but can I also find out from which directory that command was run? I am using C-shell in Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type `history` you will get a history of the commands you issued. You can locate the command you want and look at the entries above to see what `cd` commands are there. This *may* give you the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

No. I assume you're using bash as a shell. Then the history is stored in ~/.bash_history. And if you cat that file, you'll see, that it only contains the lines as you entered them.

Comment: I am using C-shell

Comment: @Geek - doesn't matter, this isn't possible.